# Button colour in IE won't change. (background-image: linear-gradient)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm just wondering why in IE that the button is grey and then when you hover over the button goes blue, it should be blue and then when hover over it goes darker blue.

I've got it working in other browsers but I can't figure out the code for IE.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the CSS:

```
#mc_embed_signup .button {
background-image: linear-gradient(center top , rgb(95, 176, 244), rgb(70, 130, 180));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(95, 176, 244), rgb(70, 130, 180));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(95, 176, 244), rgb(70, 130, 180));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(95, 176, 244), rgb(70, 130,     180));
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(95, 176, 244), rgb(70, 130, 180));


background-image: -webkit-gradient(
linear,
left bottom,
left top,
color-stop(1, rgb(95, 176, 244)),
color-stop(1, rgb(70, 130, 180))
);}
```

And here is the HTML for the button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe"  class="button">
```

It's actually live in the footer of http://www.housebuyfast.co.uk. It's the subscribe button under "Join Our Mailing List Now".

Comment: Please specify which version(s) of IE you're testing with -- this makes a big difference.

Comment: Apologies it was Version 10.0.92.00.16576.

Comment: This should work in IE10...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE9 and earlier does not support standard CSS gradients.

IE10 does support them, and your code should work fine in IE10 (unless it's in compatibility mode).

If you need to use gradients in IE9 or earlier, you have a few options:

1. Use IE's proprietary `-ms-filter` style. Something like this:

   ```
   -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#444444', EndColorStr='#999999');
   ```
2. Use a polyfill script like [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com/). This will allow the standard CSS gradients to work in older IE versions.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the version of IE that you are using does not support gradients.

More info at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(VS.85).aspx

Basically it isn't supported until IE10, but as other posters point out there are alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information Michael, need to read up on this more. Damn IE forever :)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS3PIE for makes Internet Explorer 6-9 capable of rendering several of the most useful CSS3 decoration features http://css3pie.com/